# popular search statistics

Tags: php, api, search

Does anyone know a script or API I can use in my website to display search statistics (from popular search engines) for various keywords? e.g Google Tv, Black Ops..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/). Although the official API has not yet been released, [some unofficial ones exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Trends#Google_Trends_API).

Comment: thx fredley but I meant search stats for search terms used in popular search engines, google, yahoo not my site. I just want to display stats on my site. Like Google Trends.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a go at the API :)